# Kinect Color and Depth Stream Performance

Tags: performance, colors, xna, kinect

I am developing an XNA game. In my game I am using Kinect's `Color Stream` and `Depth Stream` to get the image of the player only. For this cause I check the depth pixels and find the pixels with `PlayerIndex > 0`. Then I map these depth points to color points with `MapDepthPointToColorPoint` method and get the colors of these pixels from color video.

This works normally but the performance is very bad (especially when this is for a game). When I closed color stream and set the pixels with black color (I mean pixels with player index), it's all smooth. But when I enable color stream it is not very effective.

I tried 2 things in `AllFramesReady` function for this :

1-

```
   using (ColorImageFrame colorVideoFrame = imageFrames.OpenColorImageFrame()) 
   {
      //color logic
   }
   using (DepthImageFrame depthVideoFrame = imageFrames.OpenDepthImageFrame()) 
   {
      //depth logic 
   }
```

and

2-

```
   using (ColorImageFrame colorVideoFrame = imageFrames.OpenColorImageFrame()) 
   {
      colorReceived=true;
   }
   if (colorReceived){
      //color logic
   }
   using (DepthImageFrame depthVideoFrame = imageFrames.OpenDepthImageFrame()) 
   {
      depthReceived=true; 
   }
   if (depthReceived){
      //depth logic
   }
```

The second one seems to have a better performance because it applies color and depth logic outside of `using` blocks and returns resources to Kinect as soon as possible. But when the second player comes in performance decreases drastically. But sometimes the image of the player just disappears for 1 or 2 frames when I use the second choice.

What more can I do to increase performance of color and depth streams? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any reason you are using MapDepthPointToColorPoint instead of MapDepthFrameToColorFrame?

Comment: I think MapDepthPointToColorPoint was deprecated in the latest Kinect SDK.